# Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'

Tags: ios, swift, deployment, signing, ios11.4

I'm new to swift and developed simple program.
It can run smoothly with build-in simulator.

When I'm trying to deploy to real device, it got "Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'".

I found some reference that auto signing and already set up my Apple ID as a developer account. (not enrolled to apple developer (paid) account yet)

I updated both devices to latest version. Actually looking for manual signing provision profile by logging in my developer account and also not found.

May I know, is there any way to resolve, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

[Account Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlKer.png)

[Team Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHYW.png)

Comment: Do you see your account under Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts ?

Comment: Yup, I can see. Later share screen shots.

Comment: please refer my edited post screen shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can deployed my simple apps to my iPhone last night.

1) I used latest iOS and Xcode version 
2) Sign in to my iTune account (at first I ignored and not sign in)
3) cleaned all my previous cert. 
4) check Bundle Identifier unique (not duplicate with others)
5) Team - chose personal under my account

Then, all red color error in project setting should cleared.

Finally select my device in emulator list and run Xcode.

If "Could not launch .. select your Developer App Cert. to trust it" occur, Select your Developer ID under [Settings > General > Profiles and Device Management] in your iphone setting and Trust it. That's it !!

So cooolll !! :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all, login in Xcode -> Preferences... -> Accounts, then go to general section of your target  [image]

there you will find "Automatically manage signing" option, select it. Then select "Team" it will be "Your Name (Personal Team)" and wait while Xcode will create everything for you. If for some reason Xcode fails - change bundle identifier and press enter - it will force Xcode to regenerate profiles for a new id. And... one more thing) - you will need to allow iOS to launch the app, because it will complain for untrusted developer. After installing the app, go to Settings -> General -> Profiles, then select yours and press "Trust"

Tip: spend some time and investigate how to manage signing manually. It is very important for iOS developer to understand it

Comment: Thanks. Actually I setup and Trust from my iPhone already, later share you my screen.

Comment: please refer my edited post screen shots. I'm surfing for more info. about signing, too.

Comment: so, what is the problem now? Were you able to run the app on real device?

Comment: :( not yet, I'm trying to find out more info. to manage signing manually.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that somehow I selected the connected iPhone in the list of simulators:

[image]

Selecting an iOS Simulator resolved this.

[image]

Comment: I thought that must be done by selecting connected device in first step.

Comment: I had stated, "somehow I selected the connected iPhone". I did not intend to do that and only needed the simulator. Setting back to simulator avoided this error for me.